# Adding regularizer to an existing layer of a trained model without resetting weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Let's say I'm transfer learning via Inception. I add a few layers and train it for a while.

Here is what my model topology looks like:

```
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu', name = 'Dense_1')(x)
predictions = Dense(12, activation='softmax', name = 'Predictions')(x)
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)
```

I train this model for a while, save it and load it again for retraining; this time I want to add l2-regularizer to the `Dense_1` without resetting the weights? Is this possible?

```
path = .\model.hdf5
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model(path)
```

The docs show only show the that regularizer can be added as parameter when you initialize a layer:

```
from keras import regularizers
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=64,
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
                activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01)))
```

This is essentially creating a new layer, so my layer's weights would be resetted.

EDIT:

So I'm playing around with the code the past couple of days, and something strange is happening with my loss when I load the model (after training a bit with the new regularizer).

So the first time I run this code (first time with new regularizer):

```
from keras.models import load_model
base_model = load_model(path)
x = base_model.get_layer('dense_1').output
predictions = base_model.get_layer('dense_2')(x)
model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, output = predictions)
model.get_layer('dense_1').kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.02) 

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr= .0001, momentum=0.90),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

My training output seems to be normal:

```
Epoch 43/50
 - 2918s - loss: 0.3834 - acc: 0.8861 - val_loss: 0.4253 - val_acc: 0.8723
Epoch 44/50
Epoch 00044: saving model to E:\Keras Models\testing_3\2018-01-18_44.hdf5
 - 2692s - loss: 0.3781 - acc: 0.8869 - val_loss: 0.4217 - val_acc: 0.8729
Epoch 45/50
 - 2690s - loss: 0.3724 - acc: 0.8884 - val_loss: 0.4169 - val_acc: 0.8748
Epoch 46/50
Epoch 00046: saving model to E:\Keras Models\testing_3\2018-01-18_46.hdf5
 - 2684s - loss: 0.3688 - acc: 0.8896 - val_loss: 0.4137 - val_acc: 0.8748
Epoch 47/50
 - 2665s - loss: 0.3626 - acc: 0.8908 - val_loss: 0.4097 - val_acc: 0.8763
Epoch 48/50
Epoch 00048: saving model to E:\Keras Models\testing_3\2018-01-18_48.hdf5
 - 2681s - loss: 0.3586 - acc: 0.8924 - val_loss: 0.4069 - val_acc: 0.8767
Epoch 49/50
 - 2679s - loss: 0.3549 - acc: 0.8930 - val_loss: 0.4031 - val_acc: 0.8776
Epoch 50/50
Epoch 00050: saving model to E:\Keras Models\testing_3\2018-01-18_50.hdf5
 - 2680s - loss: 0.3493 - acc: 0.8950 - val_loss: 0.4004 - val_acc: 0.8787
```

However, if I try to load the model after this mini-training session(I will load the model from epoch 00050, so new regularizer value should be already implemented, I get a really high loss value)

Code:

```
path = r'E:\Keras Models\testing_3\2018-01-18_50.hdf5' #50th epoch model

from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model(path)
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr= .0001, momentum=0.90),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

return:

```
Epoch 51/65
 - 3130s - loss: 14.0017 - acc: 0.8953 - val_loss: 13.9529 - val_acc: 0.8800
Epoch 52/65
Epoch 00052: saving model to E:\Keras Models\testing_3\2018-01-20_52.hdf5
 - 2813s - loss: 13.8017 - acc: 0.8969 - val_loss: 13.7553 - val_acc: 0.8812
Epoch 53/65
 - 2759s - loss: 13.6070 - acc: 0.8977 - val_loss: 13.5609 - val_acc: 0.8824
Epoch 54/65
Epoch 00054: saving model to E:\Keras Models\testing_3\2018-01-20_54.hdf5
 - 2748s - loss: 13.4115 - acc: 0.8992 - val_loss: 13.3697 - val_acc: 0.8824
Epoch 55/65
 - 2745s - loss: 13.2217 - acc: 0.9006 - val_loss: 13.1807 - val_acc: 0.8840
Epoch 56/65
Epoch 00056: saving model to E:\Keras Models\testing_3\2018-01-20_56.hdf5
 - 2752s - loss: 13.0335 - acc: 0.9014 - val_loss: 12.9951 - val_acc: 0.8840
Epoch 57/65
 - 2756s - loss: 12.8490 - acc: 0.9023 - val_loss: 12.8118 - val_acc: 0.8849
Epoch 58/65
Epoch 00058: saving model to E:\Keras Models\testing_3\2018-01-20_58.hdf5
 - 2749s - loss: 12.6671 - acc: 0.9032 - val_loss: 12.6308 - val_acc: 0.8849
Epoch 59/65
 - 2738s - loss: 12.4871 - acc: 0.9039 - val_loss: 12.4537 - val_acc: 0.8855
Epoch 60/65
Epoch 00060: saving model to E:\Keras Models\testing_3\2018-01-20_60.hdf5
 - 2765s - loss: 12.3086 - acc: 0.9059 - val_loss: 12.2778 - val_acc: 0.8868
Epoch 61/65
 - 2767s - loss: 12.1353 - acc: 0.9065 - val_loss: 12.1055 - val_acc: 0.8867
Epoch 62/65
Epoch 00062: saving model to E:\Keras Models\testing_3\2018-01-20_62.hdf5
 - 2757s - loss: 11.9637 - acc: 0.9061 - val_loss: 11.9351 - val_acc: 0.8883
```

Notice the really high `loss` values. Is this normal? I understand the l2 regularizer  would bring the loss up (if there large weights), but wouldn't that be reflected in the first mini-training session (where I first implemented the regularizer?). The accuracy seems to stay consistent though.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution from [Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5974433/marcin-mo%C5%BCejko) hasn't worked for me. As [apatsekin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7442271/apatsekin) mentioned, if you print `layer.losses` after adding the regularizers as [Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5974433/marcin-mo%C5%BCejko) proposed, you will get an empty list.

I found a workaround that I do not like at all, but I am posting here so someone more capable can find a way to do this in an easier way.

I believe it works for most `keras.application` networks. I copied the `.py` file of a specific architecture from keras-application in Github (for example, [InceptionResNetV2](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/inception_resnet_v2.py)) to a local file `regularizedNetwork.py` in my machine. I had to edit it to fix some relative imports such as:

```py
#old version
from . import imagenet_utils
from .imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
from .imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape

backend = None
layers = None
models = None
keras_utils = None
```

to:

```py
#new version
from keras import backend
from keras import layers
from keras import models
from keras import utils as keras_utils

from keras.applications import imagenet_utils
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

Once the relative paths and import issues were solved, I added the regularizers in each desired layer, just as you would do when defining a new untrained network. Usually, after defining the architecture, the models from `keras.application` load the pre-trained weights.

Now, in your main code/notebook, just import the new `regularizedNetwork.py` and call the main method to instantiate the network.

```py
#main code
from regularizedNetwork import InceptionResNetV2
```

The regularizers should be all set and you can fine-tune the regularized model normally.

I am certain there is a less gimmicky way of doing this, so, please, if someone finds it, write a new answer and/or comment in this answer.

Just for the record, I also tried instantiating the model from `keras.application`, getting the its architecture with `regModel = model.get_config()`, adding the regularizers as [Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5974433/marcin-mo%C5%BCejko) suggested and then loading the weights with `regModel.set_weights(model.get_weights())`, but it still didn't work.

Edit: spelling errors.

Answer (score 7):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Add regularizers in the following way:

   ```
   model.get_layer('Dense_1').kernel_regularizer = l2(0.01)
   ```
2. Recompile the model:

   ```
   model.compile(...)
   ```

Comment: Wouldn't the recomplilation reset the weights?

Comment: Actually not - I tested it and it's not resetting weights value. It only initializes new graph.

Comment: It seems to be working as the weights have loaded properly. I'm not 100% if the regularizer change is actually being activated during training as my accuracy seems very similar to running without it.  I will try to run some more tests tonight and then will accept. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko  I played around with it a little more, and I'm getting a really high loss value if I load the model (after training for a bit).  See the edit in the OP. Is this normal? Thank you.

Comment: It absolutely makes sense. Your loss has a regularization term now what makes it to have a greater value. If you want to track a previous loss add `categorical_crossentropy` as a metric.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko  But shouldn't the higher loss be reflected within the first few epochs of training with my new reg term? The higher loss only showed up after loading  my saved model. I basically trained for a few epochs with new regularization term, and during this time the loss was very low. Due to time constraints, I had to stop training and saved the model. I then loaded the model, and the loss suddenly became very high. It's almost as if the effects of the new regularization term didn't come into effect until I saved and loaded my model. Thanks!

Comment: Have you recompiled a model? Btw. I'd appreciate an upvote :)

Comment: @MarcinMożejko  Sorry, this comment never showed up under my alerts. Yeah, I recompile the model as you stated.  The upvote to the answer (I already did =))

Comment: Apparently this trick doesn't actually work. Try to print layer.losses after compilation for each affected layer - you won't see any regularizers there. However reg_loss will show up for layers where it was set during object creation (i.e. Dens(N, kernel_regularizer = l2(0.1))

Comment: As @apatsekin said, this doesn't work. After compiling the model, printing layer.losses does not show any regularizer.

Comment: What is proposed here will not work. See https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12053

Comment: As others have mentioned, this solution does not work, as the regularization is not added to the loss. Please see my write-up [here](https://jricheimer.github.io/keras/2019/02/06/keras-hack-1/) for a solution which I've found to work.

Answer (score 7):

For tensorflow 2.X you just need to do that:

```
l2 = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(1e-4)
for layer in model.layers:
    # if hasattr(layer, 'kernel'):
    # or
    # If you want to apply just on Conv
    if isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.Conv2D):
        model.add_loss(lambda layer=layer: l2(layer.kernel))
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Seems like it works for me. Also for DepthwiseConv2D layers as in Mobilenet, depthwise_kernel should be used. However, the problem I encounter is during saving `tensorflow.python.saved_model.nested_structure_coder.NotEncodableError: No encoder for object [<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7fd2f00469d0>] of type [<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D'>].`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
# a utility function to add weight decay after the model is defined.
def add_weight_decay(model, weight_decay):
    if (weight_decay is None) or (weight_decay == 0.0):
        return

    # recursion inside the model
    def add_decay_loss(m, factor):
        if isinstance(m, tf.keras.Model):
            for layer in m.layers:
                add_decay_loss(layer, factor)
        else:
            for param in m.trainable_weights:
                with tf.keras.backend.name_scope('weight_regularizer'):
                    regularizer = lambda: tf.keras.regularizers.l2(factor)(param)
                    m.add_loss(regularizer)

    # weight decay and l2 regularization differs by a factor of 2
    add_decay_loss(model, weight_decay/2.0)
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky but it should work. This works for pretrained model in Tensorflow 2.0. Please note that all the layers should be in `model.layers` i.e. nested weighted layers will be skipped. Picked the solution from here https://sthalles.github.io/keras-regularizer/

```
import os
import tempfile

def add_regularization(model, regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001)):

    if not isinstance(regularizer, tf.keras.regularizers.Regularizer):
      print("Regularizer must be a subclass of tf.keras.regularizers.Regularizer")
      return model

    for layer in model.layers:
        for attr in ['kernel_regularizer']:
            if hasattr(layer, attr):
              setattr(layer, attr, regularizer)

    # When we change the layers attributes, the change only happens in the model config file
    model_json = model.to_json()

    # Save the weights before reloading the model.
    tmp_weights_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'tmp_weights.h5')
    model.save_weights(tmp_weights_path)

    # load the model from the config
    model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(model_json)

    # Reload the model weights
    model.load_weights(tmp_weights_path, by_name=True)
    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround found in Horovod examples. The idea is to serialize model, add L2, and then restore it back.

```
model_config = model.get_config()
for layer, layer_config in zip(model.layers, model_config['layers']):
    if hasattr(layer, 'kernel_regularizer'):
        regularizer = keras.regularizers.l2(args.wd)
        layer_config['config']['kernel_regularizer'] = \
            {'class_name': regularizer.__class__.__name__,
             'config': regularizer.get_config()}
    if type(layer) == keras.layers.BatchNormalization:
        layer_config['config']['momentum'] = 0.9
        layer_config['config']['epsilon'] = 1e-5

model = keras.models.Model.from_config(model_config)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all the layers of your `InceptionV3`

```
def apply_regularization(
    model: tf.keras.Model,
    l1_regularization: Optional[float],
    l2_regularization: Optional[float],
) -> tf.keras.Model:
    for layer in model.layers:
        if hasattr(layer, "kernel_regularizer"):
            if l1_regularization:
                layer.kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l1(l1_regularization)
            if l2_regularization:
                layer.kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l2_regularization)
    return model
```